# WPF spritesheet animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, sprite

I am trying to create an animated sprite from a spritesheet in wpf. The current technique I am using is breaking down an image of containing all the frames of the animation into separate images and just swapping them out.

However this is costly on memory and was wondering if there is a way to just draw a section of an image (specify the source rectangle) rather than splitting the image up.

Comment: You should post some code so we can help you.

Comment: Maybe you if you could convert to `Path`

Comment: here is a link that describesw the current technique i am using: http://programmingwithkinect.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/sprite-animation-in-wpf-c/

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely do this.  In order for this to be supported by WPF's built-in animation system you need to animate a **dependency property**.  In your case it seems you want to animate the `SourceRect` property of a `CroppedBitmap` using a `RectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` with the `DiscreteRectKeyFrame` class.

If you're displaying the image using an `Image` element then you would set it's `Source` property to a `CroppedBitmap`, then the cropped bitmap would have its `Source` property set to a `BitmapImage`.  The cropped bitmap wraps the standard bitmap and adds cropping functionality.

Comment: Actually I just realized that the SourceRect property is an Int32Rect and not a Rect.  This would make it a little trickier...

Comment: CroppedBitmap is pretty much immutable unfortunately :/

Comment: You're right.  I was able to animate the property using `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` but it turns out it ignores changes to the properties outside of BeginInit and EndInit.